# I need to extract the element between two h2 elements with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

From the following code I am trying to extract all the div elements between the  elements using an xpath statement.  I have tried the following statement:

//*[@id="noonsite-sections"]//div [preceding-sibling::p[1] and following-sibling::p[2]]

but it does not stop at the next  but jumps to the last  element.

Here is the code:

```
                <h1>               
          <img src="http://www.noonsite.com/images/flags/us.gif/image" alt="" title="" height="36" width="54" />  
          &nbsp;Fort Lauderdale - Repair Facilities
        </h1>

        <h2 id="Boatyards">
            Boatyards


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Bradford Marine Inc</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    3051 State Road 84 
    , Fort Lauderdale, 
    , FL  33312
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954-791-3800  
    Fax:+1 954-583-9938  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:mail@bradford-marine.com">mail@bradford-marine.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>

  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Foster's Yacht Services</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    2019 SW 20th Street, #102 
    , Fort Lauderdale, 
    , FL  33315
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954-524-9098  
    Fax:+1 954-524-9096  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:info@fostersyachtservices.com">info@fostersyachtservices.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Boat Repair Shop specialising in ABS certified fiberglass construction, fiberglass repairs, full boat painting etc. 
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Jackson Marine Center</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1915 SW 21st Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312, Florida 
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:1- 954-792 4900  
    Fax:1-954-587-8164  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:JMSBOATS@aol.com">JMSBOATS@aol.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Full service boatyard. Boat storage (in water and dry rack); on-site yacht refinishing, engine repowering, yacht paint center, outboard repairs, underwater gear repairs, electronics & generators sales & installations, transport load & unload, fiberglass repairs (cosmetic & structual).
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Marina Mile Yachting Center</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    2200 Marina Bay Drive East
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954 583 0053  


    </div>   

  <div> 

  </div> 

  <div>
  Shipyard open 7 days a week 8am - 6 pm
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">New River Marina</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    3001 State Road 84
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , 33312 Florida
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1-954 584 2500  


    </div>   

  <div> 
  <a href="http://www.newrivermarina.net">http://www.newrivermarina.net</a>
  </div> 

  <div>
  New River Marina is conveniently located in a "Safe Harbor" on the South Fork of the New River in the heart of the "Marina Mile" on State Road 84 in Fort Lauderdale.
```

All Insurance Repairs, Hull Extensions and Refits, Bottom Repair & Repaint. Running Gears - Propeller Shaft and Rudder Repair. Engine Repair on all engines both diesel and gas. Engine Repower.

Fiberglass & Paint, Custom Carpentry.

All Mechanical Service & Upgrade Requirements, Electrical Repairs. Electronics Planning & Installation.

Air Conditioning & Refrigeration.

Rigging Installation, Repair & Maintenance.

Custom Upholstery, Canvas, Covers and Enclosures.

Welding Service - Tuna Towers, Half Towers, T-Tops

Interiors - Carpet, Furniture, Refinish.

Marine Storage.

```
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Willmar USA</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    850 NE Third Street Suite 207
    , Dania Beach
    , 33004 USA
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954 713 0113  
    Fax:+1 954 252 4304  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:info@willmarusa.com">info@willmarusa.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Purchase and Sale of New and Used Multihulls. 
  </div>
```

```
        </div>

        <h2 id="EngineRepair">
            Engine Repair


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Jackson Marine Center</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1915 SW 21st Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312, Florida 
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:1- 954-792 4900  
    Fax:1-954-587-8164  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:JMSBOATS@aol.com">JMSBOATS@aol.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Full service boatyard. Boat storage (in water and dry rack); on-site yacht refinishing, engine repowering, yacht paint center, outboard repairs, underwater gear repairs, electronics & generators sales & installations, transport load & unload, fiberglass repairs (cosmetic & structual).
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Quantum Marine Engineering Inc;</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    3790 Southwest 30th Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312-6701
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1(954) 587-4205  


    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:rminer@quantumhydraulic.com">rminer@quantumhydraulic.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Marine engineers 


  </div>
```

```
        </div>

        <h2 id="MechanicalRepair">
            Mechanical Repair


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Jackson Marine Center</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1915 SW 21st Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312, Florida 
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:1- 954-792 4900  
    Fax:1-954-587-8164  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:JMSBOATS@aol.com">JMSBOATS@aol.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Full service boatyard. Boat storage (in water and dry rack); on-site yacht refinishing, engine repowering, yacht paint center, outboard repairs, underwater gear repairs, electronics & generators sales & installations, transport load & unload, fiberglass repairs (cosmetic & structual).
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Quantum Marine Engineering Inc;</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    3790 Southwest 30th Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312-6701
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1(954) 587-4205  


    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:rminer@quantumhydraulic.com">rminer@quantumhydraulic.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Marine engineers 


  </div>
```

```
        </div>

        <h2 id="ElectricsElectronics">
            Electrics &amp; Electronics


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">ACR Electronics</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    5757 Ravenswood Road
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954 981 3333  
    Fax:+1 954 983 5087  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:info@acrelectronics.com">info@acrelectronics.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Safety and survival - Emergency beacons
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">E-Marine Inc</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    2821 SW 23rd Terrace
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , Fl. 33312
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1-954 581 2505  


    </div>   

  <div> 

  </div> 

  <div>
  Wind generators/solar power.   
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Jackson Marine Center</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1915 SW 21st Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312, Florida 
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:1- 954-792 4900  
    Fax:1-954-587-8164  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:JMSBOATS@aol.com">JMSBOATS@aol.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Full service boatyard. Boat storage (in water and dry rack); on-site yacht refinishing, engine repowering, yacht paint center, outboard repairs, underwater gear repairs, electronics & generators sales & installations, transport load & unload, fiberglass repairs (cosmetic & structual).
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Quantum Marine Engineering Inc;</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    3790 Southwest 30th Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312-6701
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1(954) 587-4205  


    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:rminer@quantumhydraulic.com">rminer@quantumhydraulic.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Marine engineers 


  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Wards Marine Electric</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    617 S.W. Third Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33315
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954 523 2815  


    </div>   

  <div> 

  </div> 

  <div>

  </div>
```

```
        </div>


        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />


        <h2 id="RigsSails">
            Rigs &amp; Sails


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Hood Sailmakers</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    4710-C NW 15th Avenue
    , Ft. Lauderdale
    , FL 33309
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel: +1 954-522-4663 or 954-522-6767  
    Fax:+1 954-767-0076  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:sail@sail-depot.com">sail@sail-depot.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Bob Meagher, III - Peter Grimm, J
  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Nance &amp; Underwood Rigging &amp; Sails</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    262 SW 33rd Street
    ,  Fort Lauderdale
    , Florida FL 33315
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954-764-6001  


    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:sailservice@nanceandunderwood.com.">sailservice@nanceandunderwood.com.</a>

  </div> 

  <div>

  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Second Wind Sails</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    4910 NE 11th Ave # 10
    , Oakland Park
    , FL 33334
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1(954) 767-8885  
    Fax:+1(954) 523-7258  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:info@secondwindsails.com">info@secondwindsails.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Online database of used sails for sale.  


  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">TSM Marine</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1604 SW 3rd Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL. 3315
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954-527-4141  


    </div>   

  <div> 

  </div> 

  <div>

  </div>
```

```
        </div>


        <h2 id="CanvasWork">
            Canvas Work


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Lauderdale Canvas</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1511 SW 1st Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33315
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954-524-7841  


    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:CustomerService@LauderdaleCanvas.com">CustomerService@LauderdaleCanvas.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Enclosures, Bridge and boat tops, custom fit yacht and boat canvas, cushions and upholstery
  </div>
```

```
        </div>


        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />

        <h2 id="HullGRPRepair">
            Hull &amp; GRP Repair


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Erwin Marine Service</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1915 SW 21st Avenue Lauderdale
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954 316 7873  


    </div>   

  <div> 

  </div> 

  <div>
  Hull and GRP work, carpentry and boat transportation. Boat Storage/services.


  </div>
```

```
        </div>
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Jackson Marine Center</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    1915 SW 21st Avenue
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33312, Florida 
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:1- 954-792 4900  
    Fax:1-954-587-8164  

    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:JMSBOATS@aol.com">JMSBOATS@aol.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>
  Full service boatyard. Boat storage (in water and dry rack); on-site yacht refinishing, engine repowering, yacht paint center, outboard repairs, underwater gear repairs, electronics & generators sales & installations, transport load & unload, fiberglass repairs (cosmetic & structual).
  </div>
```

```
        </div>

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />

        <h2 id="LiferaftsInflatables">
            Liferafts &amp; Inflatables


        </h2>    

        <div class="hello"><div></div></div>
        <p />
        <div>


            <div>
```

```
    <span style="font-weight:bold">84 Boats Works &amp; Inflatable Service</span>

  <!-- it looks that in Generals that information should be seen as well -->
    <div>   
    990 State Road 84
    , Fort Lauderdale
    , FL 33315
    </div>   
    <div>  
    Tel:+1 954 7797000  


    </div>   

  <div> 



      <a href="mailto:info@84boatworks.com">info@84boatworks.com</a>

  </div> 

  <div>

  </div>
```

```
        </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is horribly formatted, and it is unclear what you are asking. What does "all the div elements between the elements" mean? Show the result you expect as code.

Answer (score 0):

> From the following code I am trying to extract all the div elements
>   between the elements using an xpath statement. I have tried the
>   following statement:

If this is what you want, this should do it

```
//[@id="noonsite-sections"]//div
```

I'm not sure why you added the remaining sibling filter

Comment: I want to put each set of elements into a different column.  Otherwise you are exactly right.  I want to come up with an xpath statement that will only get the div elements between the <p/> elements so that I can list them correctly.

Comment: the problem is that when I run the xpath statement it skips the next 11 <p/> elements so I get too much at one time. I cant figure out why it jumps over them.